# docker-compose solr create multiple cores in standalone mode

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose

By looking at [this docker-compose](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr#single-server-with-docker-compose) file, I have managed to create a core and get started with solr in docker. However, I now try to create multiple core using the same syntax, but nothing seems to work. For example I try:

```
command:
  - solr-precreate
  - core0 core1
```

..does not work. I tried:

```
command:
  - solr-precreate
  - core0
  - solr-precreate
  - core1
```

.. does not work..

Not sure what the correct syntax could be..

Comment: Share  the docker file your are using.

Comment: @iSahilSharma: the file is excatly the same as shown in the link - no change.

Comment: To be clear, you want to create two images or one. In the file, it is creating one docker image using docker_compose.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with images.. it has to do with running multiple commands under the `command` directive to create more than one core. As you see in the link, you create one core `gettingstarted`. the question is how do you create 2 cores.

Comment: Check this link - https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/issues/142

Comment: @iSahilSharma: that exactly solves my problem :) Genius stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the `docker-compose.yml` file as:

```
version: '3'
services:
  solr:
    image: "solr:8"
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
     - data:/var/solr
    entrypoint:
    - bash
    - "-c"
    - "precreate-core core0; precreate-core core1; exec solr -f"
```

This github issue has the same discussion: https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/issues/188